# How to properly fetch data on user request with nuxt3

Tags: nuxtjs3

I want to fetch data when the user clicks on a button.

After reading through [the doc](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch), this is the code I came up with:

```
<script lang="ts" setup >

const { pending, data, refresh } = useFetch("URL", { lazy: true, server: false, immediate: false })
const load = useState('loading', () => false);
function click() {
  load.value = true;
  refresh();
}

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ data?.toString() }}
    <div v-if="load && pending">
      loading...
    </div>
    <button @click="click" v-else>
      load
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

I used `lazy` to have the `pending` variable, but it seems like the first value is true, this is why the `loading` state was added.

Is there a more readable and logical way to do this using nuxt3 ?

Answer (score 1):

try this composable and add a watcher to trigger refresh() nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-lazy-fetch

Comment: - useLazyFetch is equivalent to useFetch with the lazy option
- I don't really see what piece of state should be watched (pending is true at start, so it does not trigger)